# TYPO3v9: What is the "right" way for implementing a PageTitleProvider?

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

With TYPO3v9 I created my first PageTitleProvider for an extension record. I looked at the three PageTitleProviders delivered with TYPO3v9, but they use the TSFE information to output the page title, they don't lookup database records.

If the detail view of the record is shown, the page title should be set.
My currently working solution:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Acme\Person\PageTitle;

use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\ConnectionPool;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\PageTitle\AbstractPageTitleProvider;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;

class PersonPageTitleProvider extends AbstractPageTitleProvider
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $queryParameters = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_REQUEST']->getQueryParams();

        if (!isset($queryParameters['tx_person_pi1'])) {
            return;
        }

        $action = $queryParameters['tx_person_pi1']['action'] ?? null;
        $controller = $queryParameters['tx_person_pi1']['controller'] ?? null;
        $personId = (int)$queryParameters['tx_person_pi1']['person'] ?? 0;

        if (!($action && $controller && $personId)) {
            return;
        }

        $queryBuilder = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)->getQueryBuilderForTable('tx_person_domain_model_person');

        $row = $queryBuilder
            ->select('title', 'given_name', 'last_name', 'position', 'company')
            ->from('tx_person_domain_model_person')
            ->where($queryBuilder->expr()->eq('uid', $personId))
            ->execute()
            ->fetchAll();

        if (count($row) === 0) {
            return;
        }

        $person = $row[0];

        $title = trim($person['title'] . ' ' . $person['given_name'] . ' ' . $person['last_name']);
        if ($person['position']) {
            $title .= ', ' . $person['position'];
        }
        if ($person['company']) {
            $title .= ', ' . $person['company'];
        }

        $this->title = $title;
    }
}
```

I am not really happy with this solution, because I have to do an additional database lookup. The record data will be looked up two times: The first time in the show action of the controller and the second time now in the page title provider.

What can I improve and is there a better solution to do this without a database connection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done easier without an additional query. Just create a PageTitleProvider with a set method. Create an instance of this PageTitleProvider in your controller and set the title via the setter.

For example:

```
<?php
    namespace Haassie\DemoExtension\TitleTagProvider;

    use TYPO3\CMS\Core\PageTitle\AbstractPageTitleProvider;

    class DemoPageTitleProvider extends AbstractPageTitleProvider
    {
        /**
         * @param string $title
         */
        public function setTitle(string $title)
        {
            $this->title = $title;
        }
    }
```

And in your controller:

```
$titleProvider = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(DemoPageTitleProvider::class);
$titleProvider->setTitle($yourOwnTitle);
```

Did only a simple test, but this seems to work.

Comment: Cool, sometimes I am thinking too complex ;-) It works like a charm ...

Answer (score -1):

Most of time it is done with a ViewHelper. You can check in the `news` extension, the ViewHelper is called `TitleTagViewHelper`.

Comment: Yes, News uses the old $GLOBALS['TSFE']->altPageTitle version. I used it in older TYPO3 versions in the controller. Now in v9 the altPageTitle attribute is marked as internal. I want to use the new variant. I didn't asked, how to solve it. I asked, is this the right way in v9 to solve it.